# apparmor.service fails within container (LXC)

Tags: ubuntu, apparmor, lxc

I am trying to enable apparmor within the privileged container but for some reason it fails. I have already enabled the apparmor in the host kernel(4.9) and also in the userspace(apparmor 2.11 version).

`systemctl status apparmor -l` logs

```
● apparmor.service - AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/apparmor.service.d
           └─10-enable-in-container.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-07-04 13:41:39 UTC; 45s ago
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           http://wiki.apparmor.net/
  Process: 25 ExecStart=/sbin/apparmor_parser -B /etc/apparmor.d/cache/.ubercache (code=exited, status=13)
 Main PID: 25 (code=exited, status=13)

Jul 04 13:41:38 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting AppArmor initialization...
Jul 04 13:41:39 ubuntu apparmor_parser[25]: Error: Could not load profile /etc/apparmor.d/cache/.ubercache: Permission denied
Jul 04 13:41:39 ubuntu systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=13/n/a
Jul 04 13:41:39 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start AppArmor initialization.
Jul 04 13:41:39 ubuntu systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 04 13:41:39 ubuntu systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have also set `lxc.aa_profile = unconfined` in my container configuration.

Any hints will be apreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Error: Could not load profile /etc/apparmor.d/cache/.ubercache: Permission denied` - What are the permissions on that file, and is the uid/gid for the user running this service different in the container?

Comment: This might be better suited to ServerFault

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Ok, Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please let me know how can I move this question to ServerFault without duplicating it?